# return named json object in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to get my controller to return a named JSON array.  It currently returns JSON formatted like this:

```
[{"Title":"Star Wars: A New Hope","Year":1977},{"Title":"Star Wars: The Empire Strikes Back","Year":1980},{"Title":"Star Wars: Return of the Jedi","Year":1983}]
```

But I want it like this

```
movies:[{"Title":"Star Wars: A New Hope","Year":1977},{"Title":"Star Wars: The Empire Strikes Back","Year":1980},{"Title":"Star Wars: Return of the Jedi","Year":1983}]
```

Here is my controller method:

```
public JsonResult GetMovies()
{
    var model = _movies;


    return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return anonymous json object like

```
 return Json(new {
        movies = model
    } , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```